# Return a grouped list with occurrences using Rails and PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, activerecord, heroku

I have a list of `Tags` in my rails application which are linked to `Posts` using `Taggings`. In some views, I'd like to show a list of the 5 most commonly used tags, together with the times they have been tagged. To create a complete example, assume a table with 3 posts:

```
POSTS
ID | title
1  | Lorem
2  | Ipsum
3  | Dolor
```

And a table with 2 Tags

```
TAGS
ID | name
1  | Tag1
2  | Tag2
```

Now, if Post 1 is tagged with Tag1 and post 2 is tagged with tags 1 and 2, our taggings table looks like this:

```
TAGGINGS
tag_id | post_id
1      | 1
1      | 2
2      | 2
```

Then the question is how to fetch the required information (preferably without going back to the DB multiple times) to display the following result:

```
Commonly used tags:
tag1 (2 times)
tag2 (1 time)
```

I've managed to do this using MySQL by including the tag, grouping by `tag_id` and ordering by the count:

Ruby:

```
taggings = Tagging.select("*, count(tag_id) AS count").includes(:tag).group(:tag_id).order('count(*) DESC').limit(5)
taggings.each { |t| puts "#{t.tag.name} (#{t.count})" }
```

However, I'm moving the app to Heroku, and therefore I'm required to move to PostgreSQL 9.1. Unfortunately the strictness of Postgres breaks that query because it requires *all fields* to be specified in the `group by` clause. I've tried going that way, but it has resulted in the fact that I can't use `t.count` anymore to get the count of the rows.

So, to finally get to the question:

What is the best way to query this kind of information from postgres (v9.1) and display it to the user?

Comment: Is this Heroku with (dated) PostgreSQL 8.3 or (current) 9.1? Answer depends on the version. *Always* remember to add such information to your question.

Comment: Its the new dev plan: so 9.1 it is. I've added the info to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem:

*Unfortunately the strictness of Postgres breaks that query because it requires all fields to be specified in the group by clause.*

Now, that has changed somewhat with PostgreSQL 9.1 (quoting [release notes of 9.1](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/release-9-1.html#AEN110817)):

> Allow non-[`GROUP BY`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-GROUP) columns in the query target list when the primary
> key is specified in the `GROUP BY` clause (Peter Eisentraut)

What's more, the basic query you describe would not even run into this:

*Show a list of the 5 most commonly used tags, together
with the times they have been tagged.*

```sql
SELECT tag_id, count(*) AS times
FROM   taggings
GROUP  BY tag_id
ORDER  BY times DESC
LIMIT  5;
```

Works in any case.

Comment: Thanks, I have to admit that I switched from the old to the new DB plan yesterday, so I'll check this with PGsql 9.1 soon.