# Adding ORDER BY gives error "must appear in the group by clause or be used in an aggregate function"

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, sqlalchemy

I want to add an `ORDER_BY` on `car_max_price` in my query but don't want it in the `GROUP_BY`.

How to fix the `must appear in the group by clause or be used in an aggregate function` error? Any idea of what's wrong?

```
 subquery = (
                session.query(
                    garage.id,
                    garage.name,
                    func.max(func.coalesce(car.max_price, 0)).label("car_max_price"),
                    func.jsonb_build_object(
                        text("'type'"),
                        car.type,
                        text("'color'"),
                        car.color
                        text("'max_price'"),
                        func.max(car.max_price),
                    ).label("some_cars"),
                )
                .group_by(
                    garage,
                    car.type,
                )
                .subquery("subquery")
            )
    
            query = (
                session.query(
                    func.jsonb_build_object(
                        text("'id'"),
                        subquery.c.id,
                        text("'name'"),
                        subquery.c.name,
                        text("'some_cars'"),
                        func.jsonb_agg(
                            func.distinct(subquery.c.some_cars),
                        ).label("some_cars"),
                )
                .select_from(subquery)
                .group_by(
                    subquery.c.id,
                    subquery.c.name,
                )
                .order_by(
                    subquery.c.car_max_price
                )
            )
            return query
```

Answer (score 2):

When aggregating, you cannot order by an un-aggregated column. There may be any number of different values in the same aggregated group of rows for it. So you have to define what to use exactly (by way of another aggregate function).

Order by `min(subquery.c.car_max_price)` or `max(subquery.c.car_max_price)`  or `avg(subquery.c.car_max_price)` or whatever you actually need.

There is one exception to this rule: if the `PRIMARY KEY` of a table is listed in the `GROUP BY` clause, that covers all columns of that table. See:

- [PostgreSQL - GROUP BY clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18991625/postgresql-group-by-clause/18993394#18993394)

But while operating on a derived table (`subquery`) that exception cannot apply. A derived table cannot have a PK constraint.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, sorry but not sure of understanding your last sentence. I cannot change much of this subquery as it is used by other things. Did you mean I cannot sort with this kind of subquery or did you mean somehting else?

Comment: @Jean: I clarified above.