# How to get the % of a SUM colum in the same query

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery, aggregate-functions, window-functions

I have a query that SUM all the amounts GROUP BY different categories. I would like to get as well the % of that SUM amount by the total.

My query is the next:

```
SELECT category.name, SUM(account.amount_default_currency) FROM account
INNER JOIN accounts ON account.accounts_id = accounts.id
INNER JOIN category ON account.category_id = category.id
INNER JOIN category_type ON category.category_type_id = category_type.id
GROUP BY category.name;
```

And I get:

| name | SUM |
| --- | --- |
| salary | 230 |
| restaurants | 2254 |

How could I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Divide each sum by the total, which you can get in the same `SELECT` with a window function over the aggregate function:

```sql
SELECT c.name
     , sum(a.amount_default_currency) AS sum
     , round(sum(a.amount_default_currency) * 100.0
           / sum(sum(a.amount_default_currency)) OVER (), 2) AS pct
FROM   category c
JOIN   account  a ON a.category_id = c.id
GROUP  BY c.name;  -- c.id ??
```

This works because window functions are applied *after* aggregate functions. See:

- [Postgres window function and group by exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8844903/postgres-window-function-and-group-by-exception/8845062#8845062)

I removed joins to `accounts` and `category_type`, which are probably just ballast for the query, assuming the dropped joins wouldn't eliminate rows.

If `category.id` is the primary key of that table, rather use `GROUP BY c.id`, and include `c.id` in the `SELECT` list. ("name" is not necessarily unique?) See:

- [PostgreSQL - GROUP BY clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18991625/postgresql-group-by-clause/18993394#18993394)