# GROUP BY all columns of a subtable without enumerating them

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

Is there a way to group by all columns in a subtable without enumerating them all? e.g. Suppose I wanted to query something like:

```
SELECT t1.col_1, t1.col_2, ... , t1.col_n, t2.col_k, COUNT(*)
    FROM t1, t2
    WHERE t2.col1>0
      AND t2.col1=t1.col1
    GROUP BY t1.col_1, t1.col_2, ... , t1.col_n, t2.col_k
```

Writing out all these column names (moreover *twice*) is verbose if `n` is large. I am wondering if there is a standard language construct to do this. E.g. a key word `COLUMNS` used like:

```
 SELECT COLUMNS(t1), t2.col_k, COUNT(*)
   FROM ...
   ...
   GROUP BY COLUMNS(t1), t2.col_k
```

(Tag included for Postgres as I am interested in a Postgres solution if no SQL standard exists.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `t1.*` in the `SELECT` list. That's expanded to all columns of `t1`. Exactly what you ask for.

The same syntax `t1.*` is not allowed in the `GROUP BY` list. But you can place the **primary key** column(s) of `t1` there to cover all columns of the same table. Almost what you ask for.

```sql
SELECT t1.*, t2.col_k, COUNT(*) AS my_count
FROM   t1 
JOIN   t2 ON t2.col1 = t1.col1
WHERE  t2.col1 > 0
GROUP  BY t1.pk_column, t2.col_k;
```

This works since Postgres 9.1, and complies to standard SQL. See:

- [PostgreSQL - GROUP BY clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18991625/postgresql-group-by-clause/18993394#18993394)

The SQL standard would allow to cover more functional dependencies in similar fashion (like `UNIQUE` columns), but that's not implemented in Postgres.

Comment: Clever to use the primary key