# Rails - Distinct ON after a join

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I am using Rails 4.2 with PostgreSQL. I have a `Product` model and a `Purchase` model with `Product` `has many` `Purchases`. I want to find the distinct recently purchased products. Initially I tried:

```
Product.joins(:purchases)
.select("DISTINCT products.*, purchases.updated_at") #postgresql requires order column in select
.order("purchases.updated_at DESC")
```

This however results in duplicates because it tries to find all tuples where the pair (`product.id` and `purchases.updated_at`) has a unique value. However I just want to select the products with distinct `id` after the join. If a product id appears multiple times in the join, only select the first one. So I also tried:

```
Product.joins(:purchases)
.select("DISTINCT ON (product.id) purchases.updated_at, products.*")
.order("product.id, purchases.updated_at") #postgres requires that DISTINCT ON must match the leftmost order by clause
```

This doesn't work because I need to specify `product.id` in the `order` clause because of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9795660/postgresql-distinct-on-with-different-order-by) constraint which outputs unexpected order.

What is the rails way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a subquery and add a different `ORDER BY` clause in the outer `SELECT`:

```
SELECT *
FROM  (
   SELECT DISTINCT ON (pr.id)
          pu.updated_at, pr.*
   FROM   Product pr
   JOIN   Purchases pu ON pu.product_id = pr.id  -- guessing
   ORDER  BY pr.id, pu.updated_at DESC NULLS LAST
   ) sub
ORDER  BY updated_at DESC NULLS LAST;
```

Details for `DISTINCT ON`:

- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)

Or some other query technique:

- [Optimize GROUP BY query to retrieve latest record per user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25536422/optimize-group-by-query-to-retrieve-latest-record-per-user/25536748#25536748)

But if all you need from `Purchases` is `updated_at`, you can get this cheaper with a simple aggregate in a subquery before you join:

```
SELECT *
FROM   Product pr
JOIN  (
   SELECT product_id, max(updated_at) AS updated_at
   FROM   Purchases 
   GROUP  BY 1
   ) pu ON pu.product_id = pr.id  -- guessing
ORDER  BY pu.updated_at DESC NULLS LAST;
```

About `NULLS LAST`:

- [PostgreSQL sort by datetime asc, null first?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9510509/postgresql-sort-by-datetime-asc-null-first/9511492#9511492)

Or even simpler, but not as fast while retrieving all rows:

```
SELECT pr.*, max(updated_at) AS updated_at
FROM   Product pr
JOIN   Purchases pu ON pu.product_id = pr.id
GROUP  BY pr.id  -- must be primary key
ORDER  BY 2 DESC NULLS LAST;
```

`Product.id` needs to be defined as primary key for this to work. Details:

- [PostgreSQL - GROUP BY clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18991625/postgresql-group-by-clause/18993394#18993394)
- [Return a grouped list with occurrences using Rails and PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11836874/return-a-grouped-list-with-occurrences-using-rails-and-postgresql/11847961#11847961)

If you fetch only a small selection (with a `WHERE` clause restricting to just one or a few `pr.id` for instance), this will be faster.

Comment: Is there a `rails` way of doing this?

Comment: @zack: There sure is. Should be easy to translate, but I am no Rails expert. Ultimately, the code has to be translated to SQL before being sent to the DB server.

Comment: @zack, well, you'll likely have to use SQL strings. The SQL above uses features that, I believe, Arel doesn't support. So you'll have to use things like `.select('DISTINCT ON (...` and `.order('whatever DESC NULLS FIRST')`. Or perhaps you could hack on Arel to support these modifiers, but that would take quite a bit of time. Arel is under the hood of ActiveRecord in Rails.

Comment: @D-side I figured out the way to do it. Please check my answer.

Comment: @zack: I added another alternative.

Answer (score 5):

So building on @ErwinBrandstetter answer, I finally found the right way of doing this. The query to find distinct recent purchases is

```
SELECT *
FROM  (
   SELECT DISTINCT ON (pr.id)
          pu.updated_at, pr.*
   FROM   Product pr
   JOIN   Purchases pu ON pu.product_id = pr.id
   ) sub
ORDER  BY updated_at DESC NULLS LAST;
```

The `order_by` isn't needed inside the subquery, since we are anyway ordering in the outer query.

The rails way of doing this is -

```
inner_query = Product.joins(:purchases)
  .select("DISTINCT ON (products.id) products.*, purchases.updated_at as date") #This selects all the unique purchased products.

result = Product.from("(#{inner_query.to_sql}) as unique_purchases")
  .select("unique_purchases.*").order("unique_purchases.date DESC")
```

The second (and better) way to do this as suggested by @ErwinBrandstetter is

```
SELECT *
FROM   Product pr
JOIN  (
   SELECT product_id, max(updated_at) AS updated_at
   FROM   Purchases 
   GROUP  BY 1
   ) pu ON pu.product_id = pr.id
ORDER  BY pu.updated_at DESC NULLS LAST;
```

which can written in rails as

```
join_query = Purchase.select("product_id, max(updated_at) as date")
  .group(1) #This selects most recent date for all purchased products

result = Product.joins("INNER JOIN (#{join_query.to_sql}) as unique_purchases ON products.id = unique_purchases.product_id")
  .order("unique_purchases.date")
```

Comment: As for the 1st query: `The order_by isn't needed inside the subquery`. While this typically works, it's just an implementation detail that can break any time. You *need* `ORDER BY` in the subquery to guarantee the latest row. Postgres is free to return *any* row for each `pr.id` otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

To build on [erwin-brandstetter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/939860/erwin-brandstetter)'s answer, this is how you could do this with ActiveRecord (should be close at least):

```
Product
  .select('*')
  .joins('INNER JOIN (SELECT product_id, max(updated_at) AS updated_at FROM Purchases GROUP  BY 1) pu ON pu.product_id = pr.id')
  .order('pu.updated_at DESC NULLS LAST')
```

Comment: should be `.joins('INNER JOIN (SELECT product_id  ...   )` check my answer.

Comment: Thanks [zach](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2643846/zack). I've updated my answer. Did that work as you intended?

Answer (score 1):

Try to do this:

```
Product.joins(:purchases)
.select("DISTINCT ON (products_id) purchases.product_id, purchases.updated_at, products.*")
.order("product_id, purchases.updated_at") #postgres requires that DISTINCT ON must match the leftmost order by clause
```

Comment: This would result in duplicates. A product id might appear multiple times in purchases table each with different updated_at value. I want to select the product just once,

Comment: How is grouping by `products.id` different from `purchases.product_id`?

Comment: Sorry about that. Both of the are equal. I have updated again based on your code.

Comment: This is same as what I have in my question.

Comment: Product.joins(:purchases)
.select("DISTINCT ON (products.id) purchases.product_id, purchases.updated_at, products.*")
.order("product_id, purchases.updated_at")

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with this -

```
Product.joins(:purchases)
.select("DISTINCT ON (products.id) products.*, purchases.updated_at as date")
.sort_by(&:date)
.reverse
```

Still looking for a better way to do this.

Comment: Half of the job is done by Ruby here, which is much less than ideal.

Comment: @D-side the other answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32775220/rails-distinct-on-after-a-join/32787503#32787503

Comment: Whatever. I said you'd have to use SQL strings and you actually do =)

Comment: @D-side Well I don't see a better way since they are not supported by rails.