# ERROR: for SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list using order by with uniq

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have this scope on my product model:

```
scope :all_products, lambda {
        joins(:prices)
        .where('prices.start_date <= ? and products.available = ?', Time.current, true)
        .uniq
        .order('CASE WHEN products.quantity >= products.min_quantity and (prices.finish_date IS NULL OR prices.finish_date >= now()) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, prices.finish_date asc')
    }
```

I get the follow error when I try to run it: ERROR: for SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list

How I can use my order by and the query be uniq? I use rails 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need to select the columns first so you can order them later in `.order`
2. The result will still have duplicated records in spite of using `.uniq` or `.distinct` because the generated query is `SELECT DISTINCT products.*, prices.finish_date, ...` tries to find all the combination of `products.*, prices.finish_date and the special column` that has a unique value (in this case you only want the `products.id` to be unique)

`DISTINCT ON` is the solution but using it is a little bit tricky for **postgres** because of `SELECT DISTINCT ON expressions must match initial ORDER BY expressions`.

Please try:

```
sub_query = Product.joins(:prices)
  .select("DISTINCT ON (products.id) products.*, CASE WHEN (products.quantity >= products.min_quantity) AND (prices.finish_date IS NULL OR prices.finish_date >= now()) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS t, prices.finish_date AS date")

query = Product.from("(#{sub_query.to_sql}) as tmp").select("tmp.*").order("tmp.t, tmp.date ASC")
```

Comment: It works...but I still have duplicates of products on my query result. The uniq does not work.

Comment: @denispolicarpocampos, sorry it should has been `.distinct` instead of `.uniq`. Updated answer

Comment: With .distinct I have the same duplicate...that is very weird...

Comment: @denispolicarpocampos, the issue you are facing is almost the same with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32775220/rails-distinct-on-after-a-join.

Both the `.distinct` and `.uniq` will still outputs duplicated records because the generated query tries to find all tries to find all the combination of `products.*, prices.finish_date and the special column` that has a unique value but we only want the `products.id` to be unique. I have updated my answer according to that post.