# column "pedroad.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, pgrouting

```
select di.seq, di.node , di.edge , di.cost, a.geom
from pgr_dijkstra(
    'select id, target, source, sum(cost) from pedroad', 
     array(select get_source2('location1'))
     ,array(select get_target2('test4'))
     ,false) as di, 
    pedroad a
    where di.node = a.source;
```

> ```
> error: column "pedroad.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
> ```

How should I use `group by`?

Comment: Seems like you are using [`pgr_dijkstra()` from pgRouting](http://docs.pgrouting.org/latest/en/src/dijkstra/doc/pgr_dijkstra.html#pgr-dijkstra) which should be mentioned in your question. I tagged accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

There is at least one syntax error in the SQL string you are passing as first parameter: `sum(cost)` is an aggregate function, so all other columns in the `SELECT` list *must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function* - like the error message says.

This would fix the syntax error:

```
SELECT di.seq, di.node, di.edge, di.cost, a.geom
FROM   pgr_dijkstra('select id, target, source, sum(cost) from pedroad
                     group by 1,2,3'
                  , array(select get_source2('location1'))
                  , array(select get_target2('test4'))
                  , false) di 
JOIN   pedroad a ON di.node = a.source;
```

But its unclear how you actually wanted to sum ...

If `id` happens to be the PK of `pedroad`, you can simplify to just `group by 1`.
Explanation:

- [Return a grouped list with occurrences using Rails and PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11836874/return-a-grouped-list-with-occurrences-using-rails-and-postgresql/11847961#11847961)
- [Concatenate multiple result rows of one column into one, group by another column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15847173/concatenate-multiple-result-rows-of-one-column-into-one-group-by-another-column/15850510#15850510)